# Cross product related question

Tags: linear-algebra

Prove that $\langle a\times b,c\times d\rangle + \langle b\times c,a\times d\rangle +\langle c\times a, b\times d\rangle = 0$ 
where $a, b, c, d$ belong to $\mathbb{R}^{3}$.

Comment: Can you put any context and/or what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

This is effectively a specialization of the 3-dimensional [Binet-Cauchy Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binet%E2%80%93Cauchy_identity) or [Lagrange's Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product#Lagrange's_identity). First show the following (you can expand both sides to verify):

$\langle a\times b,c\times d\rangle = (a\times b)\cdot (c\times d)=(a\cdot c)(b\cdot d)-(a\cdot d)(b\cdot c).$

$\langle b\times c,a\times d\rangle = (b\cdot a)(c\cdot d)-(b\cdot d)(a\cdot c).$

$\langle c\times a,b\times d\rangle = (c\cdot b)(a\cdot d)-(c\cdot d)(a\cdot b).$

Now add them up.